# For a finite extension $F$, can we always find a an element a in $F$ s.t $\{a^t\}_{t= 0,...,n-1}$ is a basis of $F$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field and $F$ be a finite extension of $K$ with degree $n$. Then can we always find a an element a in $F$ s.t $\{a^t\}_{t= 0,...,n-1}$ is a basis of $F$ ?

For example, if we had constructed $L/K$ as $K(b) = L$, then $\{b^t\}_{t=0, ..,r-1}$ where $r $ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $b$, would form a basis for $L$;however, is this possible in general ?

Comment: [Primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem)

Comment: @ThomasShelby Thanks a lot for letting me know.

Comment: Do see the section titled [counterexamples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#Counterexamples) in that WP article as well.